# Use the smbj module without authentication in Java

Tags: java, smb, fileshare, smbj

there is a little amount of actually useful examples for SMBJ on the internet and didn't find one for establishing a connection with an smb file share using Java & the smbj module. Can someone provide me with an example?

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can find examples from Github:
https://github.com/hierynomus/smbj#examples